# How to write integration test for Interswitch WebPAY in Node application?

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, payment-gateway, payment

I have Node web app that has to enable payments via Interswitch WebPAY.

I use HTML form to initiate the WebPAY payment screen were I can manually test the actual credit card payment. The question is how to write code that will test this integration.

Comment: I have tested it manually. Interswitch WebPAY is front-end technology only. It has nothing to do with Node.js. Integration test should be based on some front-end testing framework.

Comment: So my answer to this question would be that this is not possible in Node.js because it is not back-end but front-end technology.